# delete duplicate keys from row clusters

Tags: vba

I have a big worksheet constructed from several other worksheets.  The worksheet grows into thousands of rows.  There are columns that contain keys that often have duplicate values.  Most non-unique keys occur in clusters of consecutive rows. I have code that clears the duplicate keys after the first in any cluster of duplicate keys.  Its simple, its efficient, and when applied to thousands of rows it runs for a while.  I'm trying to make it run faster.  I have an algorithm that runs well when the keys are sorted so all duplicates of each unique value occur in one and only cluster of rows.  What I think I need is to use a list of unique values supplying the advance filter each unique value.  But what that needs to provide is the list of matching rows and not the list of matching values.  Advanced filter gives the values in a Range but, while the worksheet shows the corresponding row number for each value, that row number does not seem to be available from the Range provided.

So, the data in a given column might have this kind of form:

```
header
a
a
a
a
b
b
b
b
c
c
c
c
a
a
a
a
d
d
d
d
```

and so forth.

This VBA works well but slowly:

```
Sub Delete_Dupes()  
    Dim k As Long  
    Dim j As Long  
    Dim i As Long  
    For j = 0 To Selection.Columns.count - 1  
        k = 0 
        For i = 1 To Selection.Rows.count Step 1  
            If Selection.Cells(1, 1).Offset(k, j).Value = _  
                Selection.Cells(1, 1).Offset(i, j).Value Then  
                    Selection.Cells(1, 1).Offset(i, j).Clear  
            Else 
                k = i  
            End If  
        Next i  
   Next j  
End Sub
```

I was working on improving it using the advanced filter but can't separate out the disjoint clusters.

```
Sub DeleteDupes()  
'Assumption:  all unique items are grouped together on adjacent rows  
'heres how this works  
'get rid of the empty cells that the for each loop would find  
'change them to something wierd  
'then get the advanced filter list of unique items  
'for each unique item filter for all items of that type  
'  clear the n-1 items following the first  
'replace the something wierd with nothing 
    Dim first As Boolean  
    Dim replaceEmpty As String  
    Dim things As Range  
    Dim others As Range  
    Dim uniques As Collection  
    Set uniques = New Collection  
    Set things = Selection  
    replaceEmpth = "!%*****@^"  
    'have to get rid of "Empty" cells  
    Selection.Replace What:="", Replacement:=replaceEmpty, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False    
    Selection.advancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, unique:=True  
    For Each cl In Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)  
         uniques.Add cl.Value  
    Next cl  
    'this is interesting...  
    'the row heading always appears as part of the list of uniques  
    'and when filtering for a unique value the row heading is always the first entry  
    Z = 2                                                   'first value is never the row heading (1)  
    first = True  
    For Each cl In uniques  
        If first = False Then                                 'skip the row heading  
            Selection.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=cl        'filter for the unique value  
            y = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).count 'how many did you get?  
            If y > 2 Then                                       'need more than 2 to do any clearing  
                Range(Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1, 1).Offset(Z, 0), _
                Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1, 1).Offset(Z + y - 2, 0)).Clear  
                Z = Z + y - 1                                     'index past what was cleared  
            Else  
                Z = Z + 1                                         'index past single unique value  
            End If  
            ActiveSheet.ShowAllData  
        Else  
          first = False  
        End If  
    Next cl  
    Selection.Replace What:=replaceEmpty, Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False  
End Sub
```

---

range.deleteduplicates that's pretty neat

building a list of ranges to clear is also pretty neat

I think I both of these will work well.

### Thanks!

here is the solution I composed that, in the contributor's words, seems reasonably quick

```
Sub x()  
    Dim cl As Range  
    Dim tgt As String  
    Dim dups As Range  
    Dim clearrange As Range  
    Dim x As Long    
    Dim col As String  
    Dim keyword As String  
    Dim firstindex As Long  
    Dim lastindex As Long  
    Dim uniques As Collection  
    Dim y As String  
    col = "A"  
    Set uniques = New Collection  
    Sheets("sheet1").Activate  
    x = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count  
    tgt = col & "1:" & col & x  
    ActiveSheet.Range(tgt).Select  
    Selection.AdvancedFilter action:=xlFilterInPlace, unique:=True  
    For Each cl In Range(tgt).SpecialCells(xlVisible)  
        uniques.Add cl.Value ' this is a list of unique values  
    Next cl  
    Dim ucount As Long  
    ucount = 0  
    Dim name As Variant  
    For Each name In uniques ' check for dupes amoung each unique value  
        If ucount = 0 Then  
            ucount = 1  
        Else  
            Range(tgt).AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=name  
            firstindex = 0  
            For Each dups In Range(tgt).SpecialCells(xlVisible)  
                If dups.Row <> 1 Then                             ' skip row 1 header row  
                    If firstindex = 0 Then                          ' 0-> start new group of rows  
                        firstindex = dups.Row  
                        lastindex = firstindex  
                    Else  
                        If dups.Row = lastindex + 1 Then              ' is dup.row monotonically increasing?  
                            lastindex = dups.Row  
                        Else                                          ' not increasing by one so have defined a range  
                            y = col & firstindex + 1 & ":" & col & lastindex  
                            Range(y).Clear  
                            firstindex = dups.Row  
                            lastindex = dups.Row  
                        End If  
                    End If  
                End If  
            Next dups  
            If lastindex - firstindex > 0 Then                 '  check to see if a clear is required on the   last dupe range  
                y = col & firstindex + 1 & ":" & col & lastindex  
                Range(y).Clear  
            End If                                             '  if first and second cell in filter range   are the same clear the 2nd  
            If Range(col & "1:" & col & "1").Value = Range(col & "2:" & col & "2").Value Then  
                Range(col & "2:" & col & "2").Clear  
            End If  
        End If  
    Next name  
    AutoFilter = False                                        '  turn off the filtering  
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData                                   '  and show the data  
End Sub
```

Comment: Boring block of text.  Show code!

Comment: Please provide a code snippet so we can provide help where it is needed

Comment: why not use `.RemoveDuplicates` ?

Answer (score 0):

This seems reasonably fast:

```
Sub Delete_Dupes()
    Dim rng As Range, col As Range, c As Range
    Dim x As Long, rngClear As Range

    Set rng = Selection
    For Each col In rng.Columns
        For x = col.Cells.Count To 2 Step -1
            Set c = col.Cells(x)
            If c.Value = c.offset(-1,0).Value Then
                If Not rngClear Is Nothing Then
                    Set rngClear = Application.Union(rngClear, c)
                Else
                    Set rngClear = c
                End If
            End If
        Next x
    Next col

    If Not rngClear Is Nothing Then rngClear.Clear

End Sub
```