# Need to delete partial rows in excel using vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel sheet, in which i need to delete partial data from rows for some columns for further processing using vba. Any suggestions would be great.

Thanks,

Raw data:

```
**A**  **B** **C** **D**
1       2      3     4
1       2      5     6
1       2      7     8
2       3      8     9
2       3      5     7
```

Expected data

```
**A**  **B** **C** **D**
  1      2      3     4
  -      -      5     6                  
  -      -      7     8
  2     3       8     9
  -     -       5     7
```

Comment: See similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22002851/delete-duplcate-keys-from-row-clusters/22033929#22033929

Comment: for future reference, people arent going to just code a macro for you. so if you cant find how by researching on stack, try it yourself and then post the code you used and where you're stuck, and someone will help you through it.

Answer (score 0):

If the idea is purely to delete repeating data you could evaluate each cell, look at what row your in, look at the range below that cell, find first and clear it, repeat until your find first returns nothing.